# Using Xbee pro modules underwater

Tags: digital-communications, xbee, underwater

I'm trying to use the Xbee pro module underwater, more specifically the `XBee3 PRO 2.4GHz`.
I've been told that the GHz, and MHz frequency radio waves get absorbed by the ions underwater, and that I should use kHz waves. Is that true? If it is, then is there any other module I can use? Please note that I want the minimum possible latency, and the range to be at least 20-40 meters.

Also just out of curiosity, is there any module which can provide an underwater range of about 1-2 kilometers??

Edit: I want it to be in salt water at a depth of 60m... I am aware that it is highly conductive, and creates, a sort of faraday cage... But I've heard that low frequency RFs can permeate those cages... I meant to ask if there was any truth behind that statement.. and if so... Is there any module available in the commercial market for that kind of stuff? What will it's range be?

Comment: you can run a simple test ... put a cellphone in a watertight container, such as a canning jar, submerge it, and call the cellphone

Comment: You're not going to get that kind of a range, as any research would have shown.  Look at the extremes navies go to in trying to communicate with submerged submarines.

Comment: You only mentioned distance. You never mentioned depth or whether it is freshwater or saltwater matters. 1m below water, 40 meters away is very different from 1m away, 40 meters down. You also never mentioned fresh water or salt water. I think you can forget about it at 1-2km, even in freshwater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't going to work. RF is the wrong choice for this, as pointed out in the comments.

Instead, you could use optical wavelengths - if your stations are in fixed positions it would be reasonably straightforward to get a visible-light laser link set up - or the traditional solution to this problem which is acoustic communication (perhaps audible range, more likely ultrasound).

Comment: But wouldn't it be unidirectional?? or is it possible to move around without any signal loss?

Answer (score 0):

If salt water, you can forget about it. You might get away with it in freshwater, depending on how deep you want to go.

If it doesn't work, you could also go fiber optic cable, or fiber optic cable to a radio buoy on the surface that winds and unwinds as required to keep enough tension and slack on the cable to the buoy. You don't *need* fiber optic cable as much as you just need a cable, but fiber optic has long range and low mass.